# How to invoke a function when a class in autoloaded? (Composer)

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a `Model` class:

```php
// core/Model.php
namespace Core;

class Model {

    protected static $class_name;
   
    // This methods needs to be called when a child class is autoloaded:
    protected static function init() {
        // Set the classname of the child class using late static binding
        static::$class_name = get_called_class();
    }

    public static function className() { return static::$class_name; }
}
```

and a `User` class, such that `User` extends `Model`:

```php
// app/models/User.php
namespace App\Models;
use Core\Model;

class User extends Model {

}
```

In my `UserController`, I'd like to access the `User` model:

```php
// app/controllers/UserController.php
namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Models\User;

class UserController {
    public function index() {
        $class = User::className();
        echo $class; // -> 'User' and NOT 'Model'!
    }
}
```

As you can see, in the controller I am trying to call a static method `className` on the `User` model and expect to get `'User'` as the result thanks to the late static binding. However, in order for this to work, I need to make sure that **whenever `User.php` class is loaded, a method called `init`** (defined in `User`'s parent class - `Model`) **should be called**.

How can I achieve this given that I am using Composer to autoload my classes? (hopefully *without* modifying any of Composer's internal files) I tried to call `spl_autoload_register('init')` at the very end of the file in `Model.php` but it resulted in a fatal error.

#### EDIT

There are a **dozen** more classes that extend `Model.php`. Hence, it would be an overkill to call `<ModelClass>::init()` at the end of each file. Is there a better approach?

Comment: From where are you calling UserController class

Comment: @M A SIDDIQUI Please see my edit.

Comment: As your user class is not static you can use  constructor where you can call init function

Comment: @M A SIDDIQUI Hmm I think it won't work. Notice `$class = User::className();` in `UserController.php` -- it makes a static call without initializing `User.php` class. That's the idea -- access static properties without creating an object instance.

Answer (score 0):

There already is a PHP feature built in since 5.5.0:

```
class UserController {
    public function index() {
        $class = User::class; // magic constant inside every class
        echo $class; // outputs the fully qualified class name: "App\Models\User"
    }
}
```

No need for the `classname()` static method or any initialization.